# jQuery within Wordpress - Not doing nothing

Tags: wordpress

I want to add some code in my wordpress theme. I've tested it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/UYMxa/250/

I've tried adding it to my wordpress site, by adding custom links in sidebar widget, and js/css in a header/footer plugin but it doesn't work.

I have then replaced $ to jQuery but still no luck?

```
$('#affiliateLink').click( function () {
        $("#fb_pixel").addClass("fb_conversion");
        console.log("click");
 });
```

Comment: show your wordpress site with this code

Comment: http://totalholidays.co.uk

Comment: I dont see your id anywhere

Comment: If you click a post (destination)

Comment: where's the button of "affiliatelink" on it?

Comment: For Fantastic Offers On This Travel Package CLICK HERE!

Comment: you're doing it wrong, explain what you actually want to achieve so that we can help

Comment: Click the link and the red background to change to green - like the example i made

Comment: clicking the link will take the user to next page too

Comment: @BCLtd i've tested my solution in the following code, and it's working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set click handler after the DOM is ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#affiliateLink').click( function () {
            jQuery("#fb_pixel").addClass("fb_conversion");
            console.log("click");
    });
});
```

And use jQuery instead of $ because you are in noConflict jQuery mode.

Comment: This worked! thanks so much - I should of noticed this

Answer (score 0):

You should use $('').on('click', function() {} structure of you code. Then check if you have added jQuery library properly . It might by also some issue with others jQuery functions so try wrap your code into IFFE

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression